# Representing data on thematic map in only two colors in qgis

Tags: qgis, symbology, thematic-map

I am very new to qgis, and i am doing a project on representing child immunization on thematic maps.

I want to represent the data which is even number in one color and odd number data in another color, i tried representing it in a thematic map.

In the style tab of layer properties I selected it as categorized and then selected the column which I want to represent it on map and selected color in color ramp and then classified it,but I don't know how to show even data in one color and odd data in one color.

Answer (score 19):

You can use **Rule Based Styles** for this.

Go to the `Style` tab of layer properties and choose `Rule Based` from the drop down menu (where you selected categorized before).

Click on `add rule` (a small `plus` icon on the bottom of the window) and the `Rule Properties` window will open, Label it as `Odd`, in the `filter` use your data column (mine was category) % 2 = 1 (odd numbers will have a remainder of 1 when divided by 2). Then set the symbology you want to apply to the style.
[image]

Similarly add another Rule, this time for `Even` values ( remainder 0, since even numbers will be divisible by 2 ):
[image]

Click OK and it's done.

Comment: your information helped me alot